# How to convert the download program to async?

Tags: f#, f#-data

I have the following code

```
open FSharp.Data

let downloadFile link =
    ......
    use os = File.Create(...)
    Http.RequestStream(....).ReponseStream.CopyTo(os)

let rec consume() = async {
    ......
    |> Seq.iter (fun x ->
        xxx |> Seq.iter(fun link ->
            downloadFile link
    ))
}
```

I found that the sync downloading makes the code not run concurrently. So I'm trying to do somthing like the following. How to change it to use the FSharp.Data http `AsyncRequestStream`? Maybe the `CopyTo` can be async too?

```
open FSharp.Data

let downloadFile link = async {
    ......
    use os = File.Create(...)
    Http.AsyncRequestStream(....).ReponseStream.CopyTo(os) // Error
}

let rec consume() = async {
    ......
    |> Seq.iter (fun x -> 
        xxx |> Seq.iter(fun link ->
            downloadFile link |> Async.Start // do! downloadFile link????
   ))
}
consume() |> Async.RunSynchronously
```

Comment: Using async workflows will not automatically make code run concurrently; it'll make it run asynchronously, as the name implies.

Comment: Agreed. I have a produce/consume code so I hope the blocking downloading/writing will yield to anothers. May I should use actor or Task to do the parallelism

Answer (score 2):

Here's a skeleton solution, worthy of all the blank spots in your example:

```
let downloadFile link = 
    async {
        ......
        use os = File.Create(...)
        let! resp = Http.AsyncRequestStream(....)
        return resp.ReponseStream.CopyTo(os)
    }

let consume link = 
    async {
        let comps : Async<unit> [] = 
            xxx 
            |> Seq.map (fun link -> downloadFile link)
            |> Array.ofSeq
        return! Async.Parallel comps                
    }
```

I think you should read up on [asynchronicity and concurrency in general](http://blog.stevenedouard.com/asynchronousness-vs-concurrency/), as well as [how to use it in F# in particular](https://fsharpforfunandprofit.com/posts/concurrency-async-and-parallel/). From the OP it seems the whole thing is a bit hazy to you.

**Edit**: to answer the question in the comment:

With `return!` (or `let!`, or `do!`) you execute the nested workflow asynchronously, then pick up executing the current workflow from that point. That is, everything "below" the `do!` is put into a continuation that gets called once the thing "after" the `do!` finishes.

Whereas `Async.Start` fires up the workflow on (another) background thread and returns immediately without waiting for it to finish.

Comment: What's the difference between `return! downloadFile link` and `downloadFile link |> Async.Start` here?

Comment: I got error when using `return!` "The construct may only be used within computation expressions....` because the code is called in a lamda. I will update the question.

Comment: I tried the new code but got the error of `This expression was expected to have type unit but here has type Async<unit>` on line `downloadFile link`

Comment: @dc7a9163d9: I think you should really brush up on the basics if that stops you.

Comment: I updated the question. There are two layer of `Seq.iter` and not sure if it cause the problem. I will study the async. BTW, will `|> Async.Start` do the job here? I will switch to it since it doesn't give the error.

Comment: @dc7a9163d9: You tell me. `Async.Start` is fire and forget. You don't get a value back, you can't synchronize after the work is done. If that somehow works for you, then I suppose it does the job. But the prime reason people use `async` is to do exactly the opposite.